# Is there any way to set environment variable of U-boot from linux userspace terminal?

Tags: beagleboneblack, u-boot

Can anyone tell me how to set environment variable of U-boot from normal user space terminal, i.e, once the kernel image loaded, then I need to open terminal and change the environment variable in u-boot, in next reboot the change in environment variable of U-boot should be reflected.

Answer (score 1):

Look at `/boot/uEnv.txt` or `/boot/boot.txt` depending on your distribution.
For the latter, you might need to run `mkscr` after modifying it.